# Do I need to regenerate wsdl file with every update?

Tags: c#, wsdl, salesforce

I just got thrown into a SalesForce project and logged into SalesForce for first time ever 2 days ago. I have to add about 2000 records to a custom table (or Object as they are called) once a month.  I've never used a .wsdl file before as 99% of my development has been Winforms, Windows Services, etc. Ok here is my question:

Since the .wsdl file is generated will I need to get the new .wsdl and recompile my C# project every time that someone adds a custom field to SalesForce?  Or will my "old" version of the file work as long as I'm not using any of the new objects in my application?  Is there a way to get the newest .wsdl file into my application on demand?  Or do I always have to go into SalesForce and regenerate it?

Sorry if this question sounds stupid, but like I said I have not ever used SalesForce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to access the new fields/objects, then there's no need to update the wsdl & rebuild.

Comment: Thank you that is what I was hoping.